# Then determine whether the assertion is true for functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Prove that if $F$ is continuous map of $[a,b]$ into $[a,b]$, then $F$ must have a fixed point. Then determine whether the assertion is true for functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

**Proof:**  Suppose $F:[a,b]\to[a,b]$ is a continuous function. We need to show that $F$ must have a fixed point. i.e. $F(r)=r$ for a $r\in [a,b]$.

Let $G(x)=F(x)-x$. Since the sum of continuous functions is also continuous, $g$ is continuous. Since $f(a)\geq a$ and $f(b) \leq b$, then $g(a)\geq 0$ and $g(b) \leq 0$. By the Intermediate Value Theorem, there exists $r\in[a,b]$ such that $$g(r)=0 \iff f(r)-r=0 \iff f(r)=r.$$  Hence $F$ must have a fixed point.

Now, when it comes to whether or not this assertion is true for functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. I know that the proof above doesn't work because we won't be able to apply the Intermediate Value Theorem. But I feel like that isn't enough of reason.

Comment: No, you have to find a counterexample; a continuous function $f$ on the reals with no fixed points. (They aren't hard to find.)

Comment: So would $x^3-R$ where $\neq 0$ work?

Comment: study the function $e^{x} - x$ and you wille find that  $e^{x}$ don't have any fixed point

Comment: @UsernameUnknown Even easier: $f(x)=x+1$. Then $f(x)-x=1$ everywhere, which cannot have any roots.

Comment: For an example on a bounded closed interval let $[a,b]=[0,1].$  Let  $f(x)=x^2$ for $ 0<x<1$. Let $f(0)=1$ and $f(1)=0.$ .....  The function $g(x)=x^2$ has just $2$ fixed points ($0$ and $1$) so if we let $f(x)=g(x)$ when $x$ is not a fixed point of $g$, and replace the points $(0,0), (1,1)$ on the graph of $g$ with the points $(0,1),(1,0)$ then we get a function $f$ with the same range as $g$ and with no fixed points.